# How can I hook up a row delete button to my GridView_RowDeleted event?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a `GridView` and set its header:

```
<asp:GridView ID="ProductsGridView" 
    DataSourceID="ProductsDataSource"
    AllowPaging="True" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" 
    AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True"
    AutoGenerateEditButton="True"
    OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" 
    OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" 
    OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" 
    OnRowDeleted="ProductsGridView_RowDeleted" 
    onselectedindexchanged="ProductsGridView_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

I can see the delete button on the grid, but when I double-click on that button, Visual Studio takes me to:

```
protected void ProductsGridView_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

instead of:

```
protected void ProductsGridView_RowDeleted(object sender, GridViewDeletedEventArgs e).
```

this event doesn't have info about the sending row. What am I missing?

Comment: I think you're leaving some code out of your example above that's causing the SelectedIndexChanged event to fire before/instead of the Deleting then Deleted event. The above code should work as specified.

Comment: this is what i am trying to understand- it keep send me to

Answer (score 0):

I usually do the following:

```
<asp:GridView ID="ProductsGridView" 
    DataSourceID="ProductsDataSource"
    AllowPaging="True" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" 
    AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True"
    AutoGenerateEditButton="True"
    OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" 
    OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" 
    OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" 
    onrowdeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting"

protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rather suggest you a easy way, if you are concerned about deleting only, not inline editing of values in grid itself.

```
    <asp:GridView ID="ProductsGridView" DataSourceID="ProductsDataSource"
              AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" 
              AutoGenerateEditButton="True" OnRowCommand="Gridview1_RowCommand">
    <columns>
       <table>
          <tr>
            <td> col1val1 </td>
            <td> col1val1 </td>
            <td> col1val1 </td>
            <td> col1val1 </td>
            <td> col1val1 </td>
            <td> <asp:Button Id="btnDelete" CommandName="DeleteRow" 
                  CommandArgument='<%#Eval("PrimaryKeyFromTheDataSource") %>' 
                 Text="Delete" Tooltip="DeleteCurrentRow" 
                onclientclick='return confirm("Are you certain to delete?");'/>
             </td>

          </tr>
       </table>
    <columns>
</asp:Gridview>`
```

C# - in row command event

```
int i = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
if(e.commandname.equals("deleterow"))
{
   DeleteItemById(i);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Protected void CustomersGridView_RowDeleting(Object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
   TableCell cell = CustomersGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2];
   if (cell.Text == "Beaver")
   { 
       e.Cancel = true;
       Message.Text = "You cannot delete customer Beaver.";
   }
   else
   {
       Message.Text = "";
   }
}  
<asp:GridView ID="CustomersGridView" runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="CustomersSqlDataSource" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" 
    OnRowDeleting="CustomersGridView_RowDeleting"
    DataKeyNames="CustomerID,AddressID">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" 
            HeaderText="FirstName" SortExpression="FirstName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" 
            SortExpression="LastName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" 
            SortExpression="City" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="StateProvince" HeaderText="State" 
            SortExpression="StateProvince" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: thank you, i can see what you are dpoing here but still i have this problem- because the raising event (at your code ) is SelectedIndexChanged
and not "CustomersGridView_RowDeleting" event.
amy ideas?

Comment: void ItemsGridView_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 GridViewRow row = ItemsGridView.SelectedRow;
 Message.Text = “You selected “ + row.Cells[2].Text + “.”;
}

Comment: You can do delete by this:

<asp:linkbutton runat="server" id="lbtnDelete" on click="lbtndelete_click" commandargument='<%#Eval("ID")%>'>Delete</delete>

on page behind

Protected void lbtndelete_click(object sender,eventargs e){

int id=Convert.toint32(((LinkButton)sender).CommandArgument);


}

Comment: finally it works!
it happen when i used the seconed example.
i still cant understand why i couldnt use the "normal" Deleting grid event.
but many thanks any way.